# How to filter in SLQAlchemy - SQLite

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How can I filter the table to get only results with x name.

```
@app.route('/view/<name>')
def view(name):
    viewer = Tickets.query.filter(name)
```

This is what I did but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it the name of the column name and then which value you want to filter for (name=name).
Also you need .all() for find all results, or .first() to find only the first result

```
viewer = Tickets.query.filter_by(name=name).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer is correct if you wanna use `filter_by`.
In the case of filter although you want to do something like:

```
viewer = Tickets.query.filter(Tickets.name==name).all()
```